# Issues with using Grails criteria with associations and paging

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I'm having some issues getting the results I want using the criteria builder. Let's say I have a domain object `User` that has a `Company`. Now I want to search, with paging:

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    or {
        ilike("name", someSearchTerm)
        ilike("username", someSearchTerm)
        company {
            ilike("name", someSearchTerm)
        }
    }
}
```

This resulted in using a inner join with the association, which lead me to do:

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    createAlias("company", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    or {
        ilike("name", someSearchTerm)
        ilike("username", someSearchTerm)
        ilike("c.name", someSearchTerm)
    }
}
```

This now works perfectly. However this leads me to the first question. `CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN` is deprecated. What should it be replaced with?

Also, part of the paging should be taking ordering into consideration. The documentation clearly states that I can do:

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    createAlias("company", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    or {
        ilike("name", someSearchTerm)
        ilike("username", someSearchTerm)
        ilike("c.name", someSearchTerm)
    }
    order("someAttribute", "asc")
}
```

but this results in an error, stating that `order` cannot take `String, String` as arguments. Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I have found the issue. I had a variable declared earlier called order that I was using, and the closure was trying to use that instead of the criteria method.

Comment: This just saved my day! Thanks! Couldn't figure out what the heck was going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. I had a variable declared earlier called `order` that I was using, and the closure was trying to use that instead of the criteria method.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
createAlias("company", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
or {
    ilike("name", someSearchTerm)
    ilike("username", someSearchTerm)
    ilike("c.name", someSearchTerm)
}
order(Order.asc('someAttribute'))
}
```

Comment: Same issue: `No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query$Order)`.

Comment: I have found the issue. I had a variable with the name `order` declared earlier in the code.